# Using Jython through IPython: is readline still an issue?

Tags: python, jython, ipython

I'd like to use the Jython interpreter with IPython, so that I could use things like tab completion and perhaps the IPython notebook. The [IPython FAQ site](http://ipython.org/faq.html) steps around whether this is possible. I have two questions:

1. Say Jython *could* work with IPython: how do I actually go about tying them together? When I execute `$ ipython`, I'm running a Python interpreter. How do I set up IPython so that I run a Jython interpreter?
2. Even if I knew how to do #1, I've searched around and it seems like the effort to get Jython working with IPython has been ditched, perhaps for the readline issues mentioned on that FAQ site. However, searching has shown that readline should work in Jython; see [jython wiki](http://wiki.python.org/jython/ReadlineSetup). So, the question here is: is it now possible to use Jython in IPython, if some sort of readline functionality is available?

Comment: ipython 0.10.2 works -- have a look at https://github.com/seletz/ipython/tree/0.10.2-jython

Comment: This is probably a silly question, but how do you choose the Python/Jython that IPython uses?

Comment: There is someone working on Jython support https://github.com/ipython/ipython/pull/4226

Comment: You install IPython for each Python that you want to use. If all of your Pythons share the same bin path for installing executable scripts, the last one you install will take over the name `ipython` (although you may also have `ipython-2.7`, `ipython-2.5`, etc.), but you can always copy and/or rename them, so you have `ipython-c` and `ipython-j`, or whatever you want to call them.

Answer (score 1):

Sadly, I don't think it is really possible. It might be because ipython has some explicit dependencies on the underlying OS, which
doesn't work so well on Jython because it's dispatching on an os computer. Ipython considers this a bug that will be fixed in the future on their website. Hope this helped!