# Running Jython with IPython

Tags: ipython, jython

Is there a way to configure IPython to use an alternative interpreter like Jython? I'd like to be able to quickly experiment with Jython and the JVM and test libraries that I've written. IPython is awesome for regular CPython testing, and I'm hoping to be able to use it with Jython.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using Jython through IPython: is readline still an issue?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15576355/using-jython-through-ipython-is-readline-still-an-issue)